# MATLAB VS Python indexing , IndexError: index 9654 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9654?

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

I am coverting a Matlab code into python.
I got this error :

```
a[n_max] = 0
IndexError: index 9654 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9654
```

While excecuting this code (n_max ins an integer):

```
for i in range(n_max):
    a[i] = 1/dx2
    c[i] = 1 / dx2
    b[i] = -(2/dx2+np.exp(fi[i])+np.exp(-fi[i]))
    f[i] = np.exp(fi[i]) - np.exp(-fi[i]) - dop[i] - fi[i]*(np.exp(fi[i])+np.exp(-fi[i]))
a[1] = 0
c[1] = 0
b[1] = 1
f[1] = fi[1]
a[n_max] = 0 #error happens here
```

Here is the matlab code:

```
for i = 1: n_max
    a(i) = 1/dx2;
    c(i) = 1/dx2;
    b(i) = -(2/dx2+exp(fi(i))+exp(-fi(i)));
    f(i) = exp(fi(i)) - exp(-fi(i)) - dop(i) - fi(i)*(exp(fi(i))+exp(-fi(i)));
 end
a(1) = 0;
c(1) = 0;
b(1) = 1;
f(1) = fi(1);
a(n_max) = 0;
```

I understand the error, so I tried to fix it by changing the last line to

```
 a[n_max-1] = 0
```

I am not sure about my modification, is it the right way?
Could someone explain this slight discrepancy in indexing between matlab and python!

Comment: In MATLAB you are looping from `1:n_max`, whereas, in Python, `range(n_max)` means you getting the values from `0` to `n_max-1`.
Your modification is correct.

Comment: thanks, much appreciated!